# Netbeans UI empty in DWM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans, dwm

I'm trying to use dwm Windows Manager, everything is fine (1mb ram ;) but when I run netbeans it load but with a grey and empty interface. (it works fine in Unity or E17 )

Any Idea ?

I have found out this http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86253
but the solutions proposed doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you mean 1 **GB** of RAM?

Comment: I mean dwm consumes 1mb of ram

Comment: Ah. Got'cha. I thought you meant altogether for your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your issue is the same as this xmonad issue?

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#Problems_with_Java_applications.2C_Applet_java_console

> The Java gui toolkit has a hardcoded list of so-called
>   "non-reparenting" window managers. xmonad is not on this list (nor are
>   many of the newer window managers). Attempts to run Java applications
>   may result in `grey blobs' where windows should be, as the Java gui
>   code gets confused.

A solution is to export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1.

Edit:
According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dwm#Fixing_misbehaving_Java_applications, you can also use "wmname LG3D" to hack the window manager's name.

Comment: thank you:
this fixed the issue `wmname LG3D`

Comment: Thanks, and I was about to think the window manager I'm working on is broken.

Comment: By the way, where can one find the aforementioned list of window managers for the current version of Java?